# Show that each vertex $v$ of a tree $T$ appears $\deg(v)-1$ times in Prüfer sequence of $T$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, induction, trees

Show that each vertex $v$ of a tree $T$ appears $\deg(v)-1$ times in Prüfer sequence of $T$.

Could you do this by induction on $n$ where $n$ is the number of vertices in a graph?

So far, I have my *base case* $n=2$ in which case both vertices have degree $1$ and since the Prüfer encoding is empty, the base case holds.

How would I go from here? Or am I going about it in completely the wrong way?

Comment: This came up recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667780/proof-using-pr%c3%bcfer-encoding